# upgrade from bootstrap-sass 3 to bootstrap 4.00 alpha 2 in Laravel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, npm

How can this be done? Is it a matter of modyfying the package.json ?
If so how?

actual:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "*",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

I tried to `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2`

and got:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chris/www/project/node_modules/gulp-logger/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chris/www/project/node_modules/gulp-phpspec/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chris/www/project/node_modules/gulp-phpunit/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chris/www/project/node_modules/purdy/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chris/www/project/node_modules/recast/package.json'
```

Answer (score 2):

The package you're using is just a trimmed down implementation of BS3 that can be managed through NPM; so let's just use the V4 from Twitter instead.

```
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2",
```

Inside of your `node_modules` directly, you'll now find bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss, and all of the other mixins, you can compile from this accordingly.

Comment: ok so now I have the bootstrap folder under node-modules, it seems different from what bootstrap-sass was, eg, where are assets? I was using @import 'node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';  Now there's an scss folder http://i.imgur.com/xAcuSfr.png

Comment: ok I managed to do it but version 4 completely ruined my layout, I had to revert to bootstrap-sass

Comment: @Chriz74 There are actually a ton of differences between the two. The layouts have changed to use `rems` instead of `pxs` on the breakpoints. `panel` support has been removed and replaced with `cards`, class helpers have breakpoints added now, such as `hide` is now `hidden-xs-up` for hiding on everything from XS up, `text-center`, is now `text-xs-center` for having centered text on xs and everything larger. `tabs` now have the `.active` class managed on the `anchor` as opposed to the `list item`. There's a ton more.